# Bounding Box Not Calculating correct position in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I´m trying to make a model I created detect collisions with a box in libgdx- I have 5 boxes and use the bounding boxes to check the collision.

This is the 3d scene with a collision:
[image]

Without collision

[image]

A that point, I´m expecting to get a collision, but nothing is detected because the bounding boxes are completely different. This are the centers of the bounding boxes for each box and the hook when there is supposed to be a collision (picture 1):

```
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BBHOOK CORNER000: (13.938202,963.2201,-2830.7458)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BBHOOK CORNER001: (13.938202,963.2201,-2788.6057)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BBHOOK CORNER010: (13.938202,1011.61804,-2830.7458)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BBHOOK CORNER011: (13.938202,1011.61804,-2788.6057)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BBHOOK CORNER100: (29.528505,963.2201,-2830.7458)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BBHOOK CORNER101: (29.528505,963.2201,-2788.6057)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BBHOOK CORNER110: (29.528505,1011.61804,-2830.7458)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BBHOOK CORNER111: (29.528505,1011.61804,-2788.6057)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 0: (0.0,15.0,-10.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 0:  CORNER000 (-10.0,5.0,-20.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 0:  CORNER001 (-10.0,5.0,0.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 0:  CORNER010 (-10.0,25.0,-20.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 0:  CORNER011 (-10.0,25.0,0.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 0:  CORNER100 (10.0,5.0,-20.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 0:  CORNER101 (10.0,5.0,0.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 0:  CORNER110 (10.0,25.0,-20.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 0:  CORNER111 (10.0,25.0,0.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 1: (0.0,15.0,-40.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 1:  CORNER000 (-10.0,5.0,-50.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 1:  CORNER001 (-10.0,5.0,-30.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 1:  CORNER010 (-10.0,25.0,-50.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 1:  CORNER011 (-10.0,25.0,-30.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 1:  CORNER100 (10.0,5.0,-50.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 1:  CORNER101 (10.0,5.0,-30.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 1:  CORNER110 (10.0,25.0,-50.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 1:  CORNER111 (10.0,25.0,-30.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 2: (0.0,15.0,-70.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 2:  CORNER000 (-10.0,5.0,-80.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 2:  CORNER001 (-10.0,5.0,-60.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 2:  CORNER010 (-10.0,25.0,-80.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 2:  CORNER011 (-10.0,25.0,-60.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 2:  CORNER100 (10.0,5.0,-80.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 2:  CORNER101 (10.0,5.0,-60.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 2:  CORNER110 (10.0,25.0,-80.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 2:  CORNER111 (10.0,25.0,-60.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 3: (0.0,15.0,-100.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 3:  CORNER000 (-10.0,5.0,-110.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 3:  CORNER001 (-10.0,5.0,-90.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 3:  CORNER010 (-10.0,25.0,-110.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 3:  CORNER011 (-10.0,25.0,-90.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 3:  CORNER100 (10.0,5.0,-110.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 3:  CORNER101 (10.0,5.0,-90.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 3:  CORNER110 (10.0,25.0,-110.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 3:  CORNER111 (10.0,25.0,-90.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 4: (0.0,15.0,-130.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 4:  CORNER000 (-10.0,5.0,-140.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 4:  CORNER001 (-10.0,5.0,-120.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 4:  CORNER010 (-10.0,25.0,-140.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 4:  CORNER011 (-10.0,25.0,-120.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 4:  CORNER100 (10.0,5.0,-140.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 4:  CORNER101 (10.0,5.0,-120.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 4:  CORNER110 (10.0,25.0,-140.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: BB BOX 4:  CORNER111 (10.0,25.0,-120.0)
03-24 01:25:23.634 17593-17607/com.gdx.crane I/System.out: Interesects = -1
```

This is my code for the creation of the boxes and the crane model:

```
    public class Crane {
        public ModelInstance modelInstance;
        public Node cuerda,polea,brazo;
        ArrayList<ModelInstance> boxes;
        int pulleyMoves,maxPulleyMoves,minPulleyMoves;
        int armMoves,maxArmMoves,minArmMoves;
        int ropeMoves,maxRopeMoves,minRopeMoves;
    public Crane(){
        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        UBJsonReader jsonReader = new UBJsonReader();
        G3dModelLoader modelLoader = new G3dModelLoader(jsonReader);
        Model model;
        model = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("crane.g3db", Files.FileType.Internal));
        modelInstance = new ModelInstance(model);
        modelInstance.transform.scale(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
        modelInstance.transform.translate(0, 0, 500);
        modelInstance.calculateTransforms();
        cuerda = modelInstance.getNode("cuerda_mover");
        polea = modelInstance.getNode("polea");
        brazo = modelInstance.getNode("Cube.109");
        model = modelBuilder.createBox(20, 20, 20, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.BLUE)),
                VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal);
        boxes= new ArrayList<ModelInstance>();
        boxes.add(new ModelInstance(model));
        boxes.add(new ModelInstance(model));
        boxes.add(new ModelInstance(model));
        boxes.add(new ModelInstance(model));
        boxes.add(new ModelInstance(model));
        boxes.get(0).transform.translate(0, 15, -10);
        boxes.get(1).transform.translate(0, 15, -40);
        boxes.get(2).transform.translate(0, 15, -70);
        boxes.get(3).transform.translate(0, 15, -100);
        boxes.get(4).transform.translate(0, 15, -130);

        for(ModelInstance box: boxes){
            box.calculateTransforms();

        }



    }
public int intersects(){

    Node hook = this.modelInstance.getNode("gancho");

    BoundingBox bbCrane = hook.calculateBoundingBox(new BoundingBox());


    System.out.println("BB HOOK: "+bbCrane.getCenter(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)).toString());
    int i =0;
    for(ModelInstance box: this.boxes){

        BoundingBox bbBox = box.calculateBoundingBox(new BoundingBox());
        bbBox .mul(box.transform);
        System.out.println("BB BOX "+i+": "+bbBox.getCenter(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)).toString());
        if(bbCrane.intersects(bbBox )){
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------ COLISION !!!! -------------------------------------------");
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return -1;


}

    }
```

I don´t understand why the hook´s bounding box coords are so big in comparison to the boxes. Can anyone help me with this problem?

EDIT:

If it´s useful, the way I move the rope up and down is by scaling the parent node of the hook (which is the rope) by a factor on the z-axis.

Comment: So your question is why the bounds of you hook model are bigger than you expected? Then consider including the values of these bounds and your expectations. Other than that, you are creating a lot of garbage, you might want to reconsider your approach. Have a look at: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/interacting-with-3d-objects/ (you want to read the tutorial before and after that as well)

Comment: The values are included right after the picture of the scene. My concern is the z-axis becuse it has a value of -2000 + while the box that is farther away from the crane has a z value of -130 whichs is correct. Im expecting to get similar values to the bounding boxes of the boxes I created

Comment: that are not the bounds, it only is the center. You are also not taking into consideration the transformation (scale, translation and rotation) of both the model instance and the node.

Comment: So the createboundingbox method does not takes into account all the transformation the node or it's parents have? Also, I will add the bounds to the question asap. Thank you very much

Comment: The bounds of each bounding box and the hook where added to the question.

Comment: @Xoppa thank you for your help. I´ve been able to solve the issue by using the mul() function on the bounding box and the transform of the model instance that contains the node.